# VueLoaderPlugin doies not return HTML used as inline loader for HtmlWebpackPlugin?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, webpack-5

With the following webpack.common.js:

```js
const pathtoresolve = require('path');
const paths = require('./paths')

const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')

module.exports = {
  // Where webpack looks to start building the bundle
  entry: [ 'whatwg-fetch', paths.src + '/main.js'],

  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.js', '.vue' ],
    alias: {
      'components': pathtoresolve.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components/'),
      'images': pathtoresolve.resolve(__dirname, '../src/images/'),
      'styles': pathtoresolve.resolve(__dirname, '../src/styles/'),
    }
  },

  // Where webpack outputs the assets and bundles
  output: {
    path: paths.build,
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },


  // Customize the webpack build process
  plugins: [
    // Vue plugin for the magic
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    // Removes/cleans build folders and unused assets when rebuilding
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    // Copies files from target to destination folder
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: paths.public,
          to: 'assets',
          globOptions: {
            ignore: ['*.DS_Store'],
          },
        },
      ],
    }),

    // Generates an HTML file from a template
    // Generates deprecation warning: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/1501
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'webpack Boilerplate',
      favicon: paths.src + '/images/favicon.png',
      // TODO This isn't returning HTML. What did it return??
      template: '!!vue-loader!' + paths.src + '/App.vue', // template file (explicitly vue)
      filename: 'index.html', // output file
    }),
  ],

  // Determine how modules within the project are treated
  module: {
    rules: [
      // JavaScript: Use Babel to transpile JavaScript files
      {test: /\.vue$/, loader: 'vue-loader' },
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: ['babel-loader']},
      // Styles: Inject CSS into the head with source maps
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: [
          // Note: Only style-loader works for me !!!
          // 'vue-style-loader',
          'style-loader',
          {loader: 'css-loader', options: {sourceMap: true, importLoaders: 1}},
          {loader: 'postcss-loader', options: {sourceMap: true}},
          {loader: 'sass-loader', options: {sourceMap: true}},
        ],
      },
      // Images: Copy image files to build folder
      {test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$/i, type: 'asset/resource'},

      // Fonts and SVGs: Inline files
      {test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|svg|)$/, type: 'asset/inline'},
    ],
  },
}
```

I get the error:

```sh
$ yarn run client-build && yarn run serve
$ node client/build/app.js
building for production...
assets by status 751 KiB [cached] 4 assets
Entrypoint main = js/runtime.06de30f0b0451051a1b0.bundle.js styles/main.3b829f3c5154760383f9.css js/main.ec103c819b2711f469d3.bundle.js

ERROR in unable to locate 'D:\IdeaProjects\AIPlatform\oml\api\client\public' glob

ERROR in   Error: The loader "D:\IdeaProjects\AIPlatform\oml\api\client\src\App.vue" didn't return html.
```

My vue template looks like:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App'
}
</script>
```

But the vue loader was invoked explicitly, so should be returning HTML from my Vue template.
This is using webpack@^5.8.0, html-webpack-plugin@^5.4.0, vue-loader@^15.9.8, and vue-template-compiler@^2.6.14 . (package.json would have been included, except StackOverflow refuses to allow posts that are too dense with code.)

My goal here is to get a html file out of this vue file using webpack. Any suggestions?
Any suggestions?